# what does `![var_name]` mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, operators

I am dealing with someone else's code base, and I am trying to decipher the following line:

```
if !foo #<~ this line
  ...
end
```

I noticed that `foo` is supposed to return `false`, but with this bang! method it returns `true`. Does this mean that this `![var]` business is similar to saying:

```
if foo != nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the above code means to run the code if the condition (foo) is false. I won't say its similar to foo != nil, its more like `!(foo)` where foo can be `nil` or `false`.

You can write

```
if !foo #<~ this line
  ...
end
```

as

```
unless foo
  ...
end
```

But as per Ruby style guide, you should use `unless`, only if the code can be represented in a single line. 
`do_something unless foo`

Comment: More precisely, `!foo` is equivalent to `foo != nil && foo != false` (as long as neither `foo.!=` nor `foo.!@` have been redefined).

Answer (score 3):

It means "if not foo", and it effectively returns the opposite of `foo`.  So if `foo = true`, `!foo` returns `false`, and if `foo = false`, `!foo` returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
!foo
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
foo.!
```

i.e. sending the message `!` to the object returned by evaluating the expression `foo`.

The method `!` is defined in `BasicObject`, and it is [documented just like any other method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-21), even if rather tersely:

> ## `!obj` → `true` or `false`
>
> Boolean negate.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the ! negates the value that follows it. In Ruby, only `false` and `nil` are considered falsy values, or in other words, values that will be considered `false` in a conditional statement like `if`. All other values (`true`, `1`, `"some-string"`, etc...) are considered truthy (values that will be considered `true` in a conditional).

So `!false`, is `true`. `!nil` is `true`. `!true` is `false`.